# Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $|f(x)| \le |\sin^3(x)|$ for $|x| \le 1$. Prove statements.

Tags: calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $|f(x)| \le |\sin^3(x)|$ for $|x| \le 1$.

1. Prove that f is differentiable in x=0. I think that I can show that $0 \le |f(0)| \le 0$, thus $f(0)=0$ and then I need to show that $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x \to 0^{-}} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$. What should I do with both expressions?
2. Prove that if f is differentiable twice in x=0, then $f''(0)=0$. I got no clue...

Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the derivative, you have
$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\frac{f(x)}{x}.$$
The absolute value of this is
$$\frac{|f(x)|}{|x|}\leq\frac{|\sin(x)|^3}{|x|}=\left|\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right||\sin^2(x)|.$$
For $1$: can you prove this limit exists as $x\rightarrow 0$?

For $2$, you can use this estimation to estimate the value of $|f'(x)|$ for $x<1$ and repeat the process.

Comment: Tried to use the estimation, but I got nowhere :/ may you explain more?

Comment: First, try showint that $f'(x) = 0$. You will then have to estimate $|f'(x) / x|$ the same way you estimated $f(x) / x$